# How to display latest posts on a blogger page?

Tags: blogger

I'm trying to seo blogger by page because the url looks natural for seo, displaying the latest post will help the page to be user friendly and increase the power of the page, so how can I display the latest posts on a blogger page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the featured post gadget, you can use it to display the latest or a special post on your blog.

- From your blog dashboard, go to **Layout** > **Add a Gadget** >
  **Featured Post**
- Select **Use the most recent published post**